# OpenFL basic install on Windows doesn't work?

Tags: haxe, openfl, neko

I went to http://www.openfl.org/archive/download/ and followed the steps for a really basic first test:

```
haxelib install lime
haxelib run lime setup
lime install openfl
lime create openfl:DisplayingABitmap
```

When I try to run it with:

```
cd DisplayingABitmap
lime test neko
```

I get:

```
Export/windows/neko/haxe/ApplicationMain.hx:1: characters 7-20 : Class not found : openfl.Assets
```

I haven't done anything before with Haxe or OpenFL so this is a fresh install. Anybody can guess what's going on? It doesn't seem to be seeing the contents of the openfl library, though it can perfectly generate the project.

(update: I tried the exact same on a Mac and it worked perfectly, so I think the problem has something to do with Windows)

Comment: did you install haxe under C:\program files\... just asking because this caused me a lot of trouble

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Windows 7 with default installation options. It seems to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the steps at http://www.openfl.org/documentation/setup/install-haxe/ and reinstall the latest openfl, the contents under "archive" folder are mostly outdated.